# Query the element in Array inside JSON column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a jason column in my postgress sql Database. I have several properties in that jason column. I can search properties using below query.

```
SELECT *  FROM public.object_reference where value->>'name' = 'Sam' and value->>'address' ='home';
```

But my problem is I have a Array inside that JSON column. That Array has key and value pair. Below is the sample of that array

```
"attributes": [ {
    "value": "Sam",
    "key": "name"
}, {
    "value": "abc",
    "key": "address"
}, {
    "value": "Singapore",
    "key": "country"
}, {
    "value": "97813245",
    "key": "mobile"
}, {
    "value": "Engineer",
    "key": "position"
},
"id": "1312312",
"type": "Job",
"classid": "1245568956643546788907634"
```

}

So i need to get the value of name in the attributes array (inside JSON column). This is `json` type column, not a `jsonb` type.

Answer (score 1):

You can deconstruct the array inside de object transforming it in a set of recordet (pseudo table) with `json_array_elements`:

```
select pair->>'value'
  from has_json,json_array_elements(obj->'attributes') as pair
  where pair->>'key' = 'name';
```

You can see a running example at: http://rextester.com/ONJZ8486